# Cassandra on mac: stopping cassandra shows error

Tags: macos, cassandra

I downloaded cassandra from the official site and ran it with:

```
./bin/cassandra -f
```

Cassandra seems to be working fine and I am able to connect to it via cqlsh

When I stop it using CTRL-C, it throws an error.

```
INFO  17:39:06 Stop listening to thrift clients
INFO  17:39:06 Stop listening for CQL clients
INFO  17:39:06 Announcing shutdown
INFO  17:39:06 Node localhost/127.0.0.1 state jump to normal
INFO  17:39:08 Waiting for messaging service to quiesce
INFO  17:39:08 MessagingService has terminated the accept() thread
ERROR 17:39:08 Exception in thread Thread[StorageServiceShutdownHook,5,main]
java.io.IOError: java.io.IOException: Unknown error: 316
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService.shutdown(MessagingService.java:750) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService$1.runMayThrow(StorageService.java:682) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unknown error: 316
    at sun.nio.ch.NativeThread.signal(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.implCloseSelectableChannel(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:292) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractSelectableChannel.implCloseChannel(AbstractSelectableChannel.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.close(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:115) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.close(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:137) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService$SocketThread.close(MessagingService.java:1017) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService.shutdown(MessagingService.java:746) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

I was wondering whether I missed any setup procedures. The getting started guide says it should running out of the box. I am using OSX Yosemite 10.10.5

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears this is a JDK bug and it looks like this could be fixed by updating your JDK,  what version are you currently on?

It looks like [CASSANDRA-8220](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8220) (C* 2.2.1+, and 3.0.0-alpha1) was introduced to work around the problem, but I think upgrading your JDK should fix this as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My java version "1.8.0_60" (Oracle Java) I am using cassandra 2.1.9 which was stated as "most stable". 2.2.1 seems to be working fine. I am marking this as answer.

Comment: I get the error with JDK 1.8.66 and Cassandra 2.2.4